# Call python script using node.js child_process

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I was trying to call a python code from my node file.

Here is my node.js Code:

```
var util = require("util");

var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn('python',["workpad.py"]);

util.log('readingin')

process.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    util.log(data);
});
```

and my python part:

```
import sys

data = "test"
print(data)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

In the cmd window, only `util.log('readingin')` is shown. What's the problem of my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no problem ...

Here is a slight tweak of your working code (I convert the buffer to string so its human readable)

```
// spawn_python.js
var util = require("util");

var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn('python',["python_launched_from_nodejs.py"]);

util.log('readingin')

process.stdout.on('data',function(chunk){

    var textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8');// buffer to string

    util.log(textChunk);
});
```

and here is your python

```
# python_launched_from_nodejs.py
import sys

data = "this began life in python"
print(data)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

finally here is output of a run

```
node spawn_python.js 
11 Dec 00:06:17 - readingin
11 Dec 00:06:17 - this began life in python
```

node --version

v5.2.0

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing the same issue, I found [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/286/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-retrieve-output-data-and-errors-in-node-js):

```
var myPythonScript = "script.py";
// Provide the path of the python executable, if python is available as 
// environment variable then you can use only "python"
var pythonExecutable = "python.exe";

// Function to convert an Uint8Array to a string
var uint8arrayToString = function(data){
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
};

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const scriptExecution = spawn(pythonExecutable, [myPythonScript]);

// Handle normal output
scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
   console.log(uint8arrayToString(data));
});

// Handle error output
scriptExecution.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    // As said before, convert the Uint8Array to a readable string.
    console.log(uint8arrayToString(data));
});

scriptExecution.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log("Process quit with code : " + code);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python code is not correct:

```
import sys

data = "test"
print(data)   ###not test
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: what do you mean by not test?

Comment: @BingGan its name is not test,  it's 'data'

Answer (score 0):

You could always try something like this:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

  child_process.exec('python myPythonScript.py', function (err){
    if (err) {
    console.log("child processes failed with error code: " + err.code);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this package on npm- [native-python](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@guydev/native-python)

it provides a very simple and powerful way to run python functions from node
might solve your problem and actually uses spawn.

```
import { runFunction } from '@guydev/native-python'
const example = async () => {
   const input = [1,[1,2,3],{'foo':'bar'}]
   const { error, data } = await runFunction('/path/to/file.py','hello_world', '/path/to/python', input)

   // error will be null if no error occured.
   if (error) {
       console.log('Error: ', error)
   }

   else {
       console.log('Success: ', data)
       // prints data or null if function has no return value
   }
}
```

python module

```
# module: file.py

def hello_world(a,b,c):
    print( type(a), a) 
    # <class 'int'>, 1

    print(type(b),b)
    # <class 'list'>, [1,2,3]

    print(type(c),c)
    # <class 'dict'>, {'foo':'bar'}
```

Comment: It looks like you are promoting your own work. [Please see the instructions on self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): "_you **must** disclose your affiliation in your post._"

Answer (score 0):

A more rigorous implementation could also catch raised exceptions and exit codes, as such

```js
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var process = spawn('python',["my_py_file.py"]);

process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});

process.stderr.on('data', (stacktrace) => {
    console.error(stacktrace.toString('utf8'));

    // possibly parse the stack trace to handle distinct exceptions
});

process.on('exit', (exitCode) => {
    console.log(`Process ended with code (${exitCode})`);
});
```

I would personally rely on exit codes to handle different outcomes from my Python script rather than raising exceptions, as the exceptions will most likely need to be manually parsed.