# How to display output of python script called from node.js

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I'm using the next method to call a python script from a node.js script ,

```
 const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
 const pythonProcess = await spawn('python', ["script.py", "test",]);
```

How can I make the python script outputs be displayed in the console along side the node.js output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call python script using node.js child\_process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213845/call-python-script-using-node-js-child-process)

Comment: @user3710700 you check the updated answer, now it seems more suitable

Answer (score 3):

You can modify a bit your nodejs code to get output

Suppose here is a python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# for-loop.py: Sample for loop to print welcome message 3 times
#
for i in '123':
        print "Welcome",i,"times"
```

Nodejs script

```
require("child_process").spawn('python', ['./loop.py'], {
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  detached: true,
  stdio: "inherit"
});
```

or you can check python process code as well.

```
var childProcess = require("child_process").spawn('python', ['./loop.py'], {stdio: "inherit"})
childProcess.on('data', function(data){
    process.stdout.write("python script output",data);
});
childProcess.on('close', function(code) {
        if ( code === 1 ){
            process.stderr.write("error occured",code);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        else{
            process.stdout.write('"python script exist with code: ' + code + '\n');
        }
    });
```

Here are the console logs from nodejs
[image]